# What protocols are common for LAN discovery?

Tags: networking, lan, network-discovery

I noticed that my XP pops up a baloon about that it found my UPNP-enabled router whenever I reconnect network.

In my windows command line, I can enter `Net View` supposedly to see computers in the workgroup <sub>(although currently I cannot see the computer next door when I should but this is unrelated;).)</sub>

Windows Media Player in Vista introduced some feature that can detect shared media over the network.

If I enter windows' network, it makes something like a samba discovery.

I guess in Linux there are other similar protocols in use that work over LAN. And in Mac, too.

- What are these protocols? <sub>I mean, more accurately than, say, 'based on UDP'.</sub>
- What other protocols are common? (eg. built-in in some used version of Windows, MacOSX, [Top10](http://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=major) Linux distro., or topping in some [category in alternativeto](http://alternativeto.net/category/) and worth to mention.)
- Is there a tool for them to list available computers/peers on LAN - preferably over the command line?

(Is there a tool that can list nodes by multiple protocols?)

Comment: SSDP, AVAHI/Bonjour, NetBEUI/netbios-ns, ect. if you really want to find hosts, use nmap/zenmap. nmap uses pure IP and TCP/UDP probes so it doesn't matter what kind of advertising/discovery protocol is in play, nmap will find everything.

Answer (score 2):

UPnP uses UDP/1900(Standard) and TCP/2869(Microsoft).

There are two options that I know of to scan for this.

This tool http://upnp-check.rapid7.com/.

Or nmap with the upnp-info script.

Answer (score 0):

nmap will list other computers on the same subnet.  You could also do a simple ping scan using a loop in Linux like:

```
for I in {1..254}
do
ping -c1 192.168.1.${I} && echo host is UP || echo Host is down
done
```

That assumes your subnet is 192.168.1.0/24

Macs use Multicast DNS ( MDNS) also known as Bonjour for service discovery.  Linux used avahi and DNS-SD for service discovery.